# Is there a best practice to call a specific function every time before any function in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, design-patterns, dependency-injection, singleton

I am working with singleton pattern, and I have managed the dependency and parameter injections like this:

```
  LocalizationClientComponent._();

  /// Singleton instance of the [LocalizationClientComponent] class.
  static final instance = LocalizationClientComponent._();

  static bool _injectedDependencies = false;

  static bool _injectedParams = false;

  late final DeviceInfoRepository _deviceInfoRepository;
  late final MapapiRepository _mapapiRepository;
  late final SensorsRepository _sensorsRepository;
  late final LocationRepository _locationRepository;
  late final BluetoothRepository _bluetoothRepository;
  late final WifiRepository _wifiRepository;

  void injectDependencies({
    required DeviceInfoRepository deviceInfoRepository,
    required MapapiRepository mapapiRepository,
    required SensorsRepository sensorsRepository,
    required LocationRepository locationRepository,
    required BluetoothRepository bluetoothRepository,
    required WifiRepository wifiRepository,
  }) {
    if (_injectedDependencies) return;

    _deviceInfoRepository = deviceInfoRepository;
    _mapapiRepository = mapapiRepository;
    _sensorsRepository = sensorsRepository;
    _locationRepository = locationRepository;
    _bluetoothRepository = bluetoothRepository;
    _wifiRepository = wifiRepository;

    _injectedDependencies = true;
  }
```

Then the same thing for parameters:

```
  void injectParams({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required Duration postFrequency,
    required int sensorListLength,
  }) {
    if (_injectedParams) return;

    _postFrequency = postFrequency;
    _sensorListLength = sensorListLength;
    _telemetryEvent = TelemetryEvent(_sensorListLength);

    _injectedParams = true;
  }
```

After that, I made this method to control whether params and dependencies are injected:

```
void _handleInitError() {
    final StringBuffer errorMessage = StringBuffer();
    if (!_injectedDependencies) {
      errorMessage
        ..write(
          'Dependencies are not injected. Use injectDependencies() before using any other methods.',
        )
        ..write('\n');
    }

    if (!_injectedParams) {
      errorMessage.write(
        'Parameters are not injected. Use injectParams() before using any other methods.',
      );
    }

    if (errorMessage.isNotEmpty) {
      throw Exception(errorMessage.toString());
    }
  }
```

Now, I am adding `_handleInitError()` to all other methods like this:

```
Future<bool> openAppSettings() async {
    _handleInitError();

    return _locationRepository.openAppSettings();
  }

  Future<bool> openLocationSettings() async {
    _handleInitError();

    return _locationRepository.openLocationSettings();
  }

  Future<bool> requestLocationPermission() {
    _handleInitError();

    return _locationRepository.requestLocationPermission();
  }

  Future<bool> activateLocationService() async {
    _handleInitError();

    return _locationRepository.activateLocationService();
  }

  Future<bool> turnOnWifi() async {
    _handleInitError();

    return _wifiRepository.turnOnWifi();
  }
```

Is there a better way than adding all methods to `_handleInitError()`?

Is there a way to automatically execute this method before any method?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a base function that your functions get passed as parameter and before each call you do your _handleInitError

```
void call(Function f){
    _handleInitError();
    f.call();
}
```

Call it like this

```
call(requestLocationPermission);
```